# Server Client Communication

Tags: java, android, web, client-server

I just want to know..  like  suppose there is a  website or say a mobile app.  like whatsapp or Hangout.
Now when ever you receive  a new message :

1. If your App is in foreground you just see  it on the list.
   Else you get a Notification.
2. Now i want to know..  like to fetch those messages the App/ website have to poll to the server.

Is their any way, that a server tells an App/wesite that you have to fetch some data?

And is their any connection between these two points.??
Can you help me understand how this work..  and how to achieve point 2.

Just give a brief idea.

Comment: It seems push notification can help to notify the application when there is new record on database or sth but I'm not sure since I'm still learning push.

Comment: please post some code of what you have already tried.

Comment: No.  i just want to know is there any way that the client donot poll the server for new messages.  server alerts the client that you have received a new mail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after the `BroadcastReceiver` class.

A simple `intent-filter` for the receiver in the `AndroidManifest` file can take care of the notification part.